# Navigation to a Specific PivotItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I navigate to a specific Pivot-item of Pivot-Page when I tap an Image on Main-Page ?

The XAML codes are following for Image on Main Page

```
 <Image  Source="Assets/5.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="150" Width="150" Margin="12,12,0,0"/>
```

And the code for Pivot-Page is following

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="fifth">
    ..........         
    ..........                      
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

I want to navigate to the fifth Pivot-Item when I tap the Image on Main Page..

Answer (score 7):

Pivot control has properties like `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` which can be set to do this.

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="pvControl">
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="piFive" Header="fifth">
    ..........         
    ..........                      
        </phone:PivotItem>

pvControl.SelectedItem = piFive;
```

Comment: Please give me an example

Comment: Those properties are self explanatory. You can assign a pivot item to selecteditem or an int to selectedindex.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to send in your navigation args the index of the `PivotItem` you want to navigate to (if your Pivot HAS static `PivotItem`s)

so you want to navigate to the FIFTH `PivotItem`, then you may want to pass a navigation parameter with the index of PivotItem (which is 4). In your `PivotItem` page, you will get the index from the passed param and select the `PivotItem` using the property `SelectedIndex`

For example, your `Pivot` is contained in `PivotPage.xaml`, then you may want to navigate to that page like so (you add the navigation call to the image tap event handler of course):

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PivotPage.xaml?item=4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

`item=4` is your navigation param

Then in your `PivotPage.xaml` code-behind, add an override to `OnNavigateTo()` method of `PhoneApplicationPage`, like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("item"))
        {
            var index = NavigationContext.QueryString["item"];
            var indexParsed = int.Parse(index);
            Pivot.SelectedIndex = indexParsed;
        }
}
```